# Broadband light term in a Hamiltonian

Tags: atomic-physics, hamiltonian

In atomic systems, for a two-level system, the Hamiltonian can be written in the form:

$$H=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 E_1 & C_{12} \\
 C_{21} & E_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are the energy offsets of the atomic levels from the zero point, and $C_{**}$ are the coherences between the levels. Now if we would like to couple the two levels with an electromagnetic field, usually the coupling term looks like this:

$$C_{12}=\Omega \cos \omega t$$

where $\Omega$ is the Rabi frequency of the system and $\omega$ is the frequency of the electric field, or the Larmor frequency.

**The question:** Now this kind of light-coupling couples light with zero linewidth. No broadband light. So my question is, how can we include light that has a linewidth?

**More details**:

Now normally I include states that have a width not using the Hamiltonian, but using the Liouville equation. It looks like this:

$$i\hbar\frac{d\rho}{dt}=H \rho-\rho H-\frac{1}{2}i \hbar(\Gamma\rho+\rho\Gamma)$$

where $\rho$ is the density matrix of the system. $\Gamma$ is a diagonal matrix that contains the linewidth of each state. Is there a similar solution to include the width of the electromagnetic field? That would be OK too.

Why do I need this? I have a complicated, large system with many levels and I would like them all to be excited together with a broadband light, kind of like the experiment I'm working on.

Comment: I think you're asking how to write the field of a broadband source. This requires understanding stochastic processes. It's not trivial. I hope someone will write a good answer.

Comment: @DanielSank Yes that's my question. But why does that require stochastic processes?

Comment: You don't need the full machinery of stochastic processes, but you're probably going to need either an equation in terms of a spectral density, or something like the Langevin equation. Broadband light is usually not coherent. This is more than I can really explain in a comment.

Comment: Isn't that already included in the density matrix approach? I agree with DanielSank that you need to work somewhat to go into a frequency representation, then you can apply a broad line and a random phase and then you have to calculate the expectation values.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm sorry I don't understand. What is included? I agree with DanielSank too, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I can have a crack at an answer, but you need to specify the state of the electromagnetic field first. Or at least give us some idea of your experimental setup. Otherwise you are basically asking for a summary of the entire discipline of quantum optics. The Hamiltonian you have specified is valid in only one very special case, a single-mode coherent state of the field. Any other case becomes much more complicated, as indicated in udrv's answer.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I'm working on the so called NV-Diamond centers. It's a very, very broad system due to phonon bands that lasers (532 nm) don't even need to be locked and all the physics works with that. The system consists of a ground state with spin 1, each split into 3 hyperfine levels for N14 nuclear spin 1. The excited states are pretty much very similar, but with a very broad phonon bands. I'm trying to study the system behavior with different magnetic fields. I'm hoping there's a way to study this system without replacing broadband with scans. If you require more information, please ask.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist OK, I'm happy with the NV centre bit, but what kind of broadband light would you use to excite the system? I think the dynamics will be very, very different between, say, a femto-second laser pulse or a white thermal light source...

Comment: @MarkMitchison It's a normal continuous green laser at 532 nm. You know even hand-held cheap lasers can work for the experiment! The system is that broad.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist OK, so actually you have a rather narrow-band light field. But of course the laser has a finite linewidth. So you want to understand transitions between bands due to absorption of laser light, which are not exactly at 532 nm?

Comment: @MarkMitchison I'm not sure it's OK to call it narrow band, but yes the linewidth is finite. Yes I want to simulate this system when absorbing light, which is not exactly at 532 nm, but it sure has a linewidth that covers all possible transitions, and I know the selection rules and want to impose them (which I normally do in a zero-width light by choosing the matrix element position that couples two levels).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist OK, well then I guess the important question now is how to represent the quantum state of a laser field with finite linewidth. I don't know the answer to this, and it's not clear to me what one would expect (I suspect an incoherent mixture of coherent states in different modes). This would be good as a separate question.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I'm sorry, could you please explain what's the difference between this and my question? Because I'm concerned about how to simulate that broad light (which is also with a finite lightwidth, I don't see a difference). Why does this require a separate question? (I'm not an expert in this, but I'm learning how this works out, so could you please explain the difference).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Your question is about the light-matter interaction for (arbitrary) broadband light. This has already been answered below. In order to solve your problem you would need to understand what is the quantum state of the specific kind of light you are shining on the system. The dynamics of your NV centres will depend on the state of the light.

Answer (score 2):

That attempt to account for dissipation in the von Neumann equation hasn't been in use for about 40 years now: it doesn't work very well. First and foremost, it "leaks" probability, since $Tr\dot\rho \neq 0$. Second, but probably most importantly, it cannot keep the density matrix positive definite.

If you want a dissipative evolution in terms of the two-level density matrix only, then what you are looking for is a (linear) Lindblad dynamics of the form
$$
\dot\rho = -i[H,\rho] + \frac{1}{2}\sum_j{\left(2\Gamma_j\rho\Gamma_j^\dagger - \Gamma_j^\dagger\Gamma_j\rho - \rho\Gamma_j^\dagger\Gamma_j\right)}
$$ 
In this case, the density matrix $\rho$, the Hamiltonian $H$, and the dissipative operators $\Gamma_j$ all act on the two-level Hilbert space only. The Hamiltonian $H$ and the $\Gamma_j$-s can also be time-dependent. This is the most general form of a positive linear dynamics, i.e. one that keeps $\rho$ positive definite at all times. You can easily check that it conserves total probability too, in the sense that $Tr\dot\rho = 0$.

A frequent choice for the dissipative operators is $\Gamma_j = \sigma_\pm$, but in the simplest possible case, the sum over $j$ keeps a single term and the evolution eq. is simply
$$
\dot\rho = -i[H,\rho] + \frac{1}{2}\left(2\Gamma\rho\Gamma^\dagger - \Gamma^\dagger\Gamma\rho - \rho\Gamma^\dagger\Gamma\right)
$$
This can actually be solved exactly. If you rewrite your $\Gamma$ as $\Gamma \rightarrow \Gamma^\dagger\Gamma$, then the form above differs from yours only by a $\Gamma\rho\Gamma^\dagger$ term.

If you prefer to account explicitly for the electromagnetic field, it can be accommodated directly in the Lindblad dynamics, provided the Hilbert space is extended to the system-field Hilbert space, and the density matrix becomes the system-field density matrix. In this case the total hamiltonian must include the two-level hamiltonian $H_0$, the field hamiltonian $H_1$, and the system-field interactions,  $H_{int}$, so 
$$
H = H_0 + H_1 + H_{int}
$$
The dissipative terms usually account for possible field interactions with another external bath/reservoir and depend only on the field degrees of freedom.

The system-field hamiltonian is known in general as the *Jaynes–Cummings model* and can be found in any course on Quantum Optics. I am jotting it down here just to make the answer self-contained. First write the two-level hamiltonian in terms of SU(2) operators,
$$
H_0 = \epsilon \hat\sigma_z + V\hat\sigma_+ + V^*\hat\sigma_-
$$
where $\hat\sigma_z = |e\rangle\langle e| -  |g\rangle\langle g|$, $\hat\sigma_+ = |e\rangle\langle g|$, and $\hat\sigma_- = |g\rangle\langle e|$, with $|e\rangle$ the excited state and $|g\rangle$ the ground state. If you prefer, it is also possible to write instead
$$
H_0 = \vec{u} \cdot\vec{\hat\sigma}
$$
where $\vec{\hat\sigma} = (\hat\sigma_x, \hat\sigma_y, \hat\sigma_z)$ and $\vec{u}$ is a real 3-D vector (possibly a magnetic field?).

The field hamiltonian is just the standard hamiltonian for arbitrary field modes,
$$
H_1 = \sum_{\vec{k},\lambda}{\omega(\vec{k})a^\dagger_{\vec{k},\lambda}a_{\vec{k},\lambda}}
$$
and the system field interaction is initially taken as (Schroedinger representation)
$$
H_{int} = \sum_{\vec{k},\lambda}{(g_{\vec{k},\lambda}\sigma_+ + g^*_{\vec{k},\lambda}\sigma_-)(a^\dagger_{\vec{k},\lambda} + a_{\vec{k},\lambda})}
$$
but after a rotating wave approximation (RWA) in the interaction picture and reverting back to Schroedinger it becomes
$$
H_{int} = \sum_{\vec{k},\lambda}{(g_{\vec{k},\lambda}\sigma_+a_{\vec{k},\lambda} + g^*_{\vec{k},\lambda}\sigma_-a^\dagger_{\vec{k},\lambda})}
$$

As for the dissipative operators $\Gamma_j$ they are usually defined as 
$$
\Gamma_j \;\;\rightarrow \;\; \Gamma_{\vec{k},\lambda} = \kappa_{\vec{k},\lambda}a_{\vec{k},\lambda} 
$$
where $\kappa_{\vec{k},\lambda}$ are complex scalars (coupling constants).

Finally, the broadband condition is not so much about the form of the evolution equation as about the initial state of the field. If the field is initially confined to a single mode, the system is basically interacting with a coherent laser mode. If instead the field starts in some pure multi-mode superposition, or even better, some multi-mode mixed state, then you basically end up with a broadband field.

Comment: "If instead the field starts in some pure multi-mode superposition, or even better, some multi-mode mixed state, then you basically end up with a broadband field." <-- That's a dangerous statement. If the field is a pure multimode superposition the statistics of the evolution is *very* different than if the field is stochastic.

Comment: @udrv I think you mean $\Gamma_j \sim \sigma_\pm$. Obviously the Lindblad operators should act in the Hilbert space of the 2-level system, not the electromagnetic field. It is also not clear what $\kappa$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: I would like to point out that I fix the density matrix probability conservation by adding a repopulation term. I'll study this solution some time later (I'm sorry I got a problem that shifted my concentration off this problem). +1 because it gave me many ideas and terms to learn.

Comment: @DanielSank Under hamiltonian dynamics, yes, the statistics can be significantly different, even coherent, although still broadband if we take the latter to mean broad(er) spectrum. Under dissipation and decoherence the difference is likely to be wiped out more or less rapidly, unless the field is externally driven. In any case, if there are questions as to the suitability of starting out with the field in a pure multi-mode state, just default to a suitable mixture.

Comment: @MarkMitchison No, in the last case the $\Gamma$-s actually act on the field. The density matrix $\rho$ lives in the joint system-field Hilbert space, it is not yet reduced to the system Hilbert space only. Dissipation and decoherence in the 2-level system is accounted for through interaction with the field, while the Lindblad terms drive dissipation and decoherence on the field itself on account of any other external interactions. The 2-level system is assumed shielded from the latter. And thanks for pointing out the $\kappa$ issue, it's fixed.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Even if you add repopulation and preserve $Tr\rho$, there still is the problem of a positive definite $\rho$. Note that if you rewrite your $\Gamma$ as $\bar\Gamma^\dagger\bar\Gamma$, the Lindblad form differs from yours only through a $\bar\Gamma\rho\bar\Gamma^\dagger$ term.

Comment: Hi @udrv, OK I see what you are getting at. You might want to consider clarifying this in the text of the answer. I was confused because your definition of $\Gamma_j$ immediately follows the sentence "If you want a dissipative evolution in terms of the two-level density matrix only...", implying that your discussion of Lindblad dynamics will be restricted to the two-level system.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Oh, now I get it! :D You were referring to the other instance of $\Gamma_j$, right after I first introduced them. In this case you are correct, $\rho$ and the $\Gamma_j$-s all act on the two-level Hilbert space, and the $\Gamma_j$-s are usually $\sigma_\pm$. The other case, with the field explicitly taken into account, is obviously different. I added clarifications in the answer. Thanks again for pointing this out. Also corrected a missing factor of 2 in the dissipator.

Comment: One question, if you don't mind. Is the Lindblad operator generally Hermitian? It looks like it from what you wrote, but I want to be sure of that from an expert.

Comment: If you mean the Lindblad terms in the expression of $\dot\rho$, yes, and they have to be because they amount to $\dot{\rho} + i[H,\rho]$, which is necessarily Hermitian.

Comment: If you mean the Lindblad superoperator acting on $\rho$ as ${\mathcal L}\rho = \dot{\rho}$, then superoperator hermiticity requires $Tr[\beta^\dagger {\mathcal L}(\alpha)] = \left(Tr[\alpha^\dagger {\mathcal L}(\beta)] \right)^*$. In this sense the Hamiltonian terms correspond to an anti-Hermitian superoperator, so no, the _Lindblad superoperator_ is not Hermitian. But it always takes Hermitian operators into Hermitian operators, so $\dot{\rho}$ is guaranteed to be Hermitian as it should.